How to use the Latin Modern Mono light condensed font with LuaTeX?
After more than a decade, I am currently re-visting Latex. So I am in fact a newbie and have a newbie question. Please consider the following document:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

This should be proportional.
\fontseries{lc}\selectfont This should be monospace condensed 000.

\end{document}

I am compiling it using latexmk (lualatex) from within Visual Studio Code with the Latex Workshop extension under Windows. I have installed the full version of TexLive 2024.
This produces a PDF document where the second sentence definitely is not monospaced. The compiler throws the following warning:
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmr/lc/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 8.

IMHO, this shouldn't happen. According to this page, the light condensed version of the lmodern font is part of Latex (and thus, of my TexLive full installation). Second, I have literally copied the code that is given on that page to use the font.
What am I doing wrong?
What I did / thought of so far:
I have found some similar questions, for example this one. But I believe that none of the answers there apply to my problem.
The first answer uses \usepackage{fontenc} and thus obviously is meant for pdflatex, not lualatex.
The second answer is explicitly for lualatex, but uses \usepackage[sfdefault, light, condensed]{roboto}. This doesn't help because the lmodern package simply does not provide [] options (at least, the README doesn't mention them).
The third answer also uses package options and thus is not applicable.
The answers to other similar questions didn't help either.

You are trying to use the 'classical' 8-bit font approach (suitable for pdfTeX) in LuaTeX: whilst this can be made to work, it is not recommended. Instead, you should load fontspec then select the font using the mechanism it provides:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
This should be proportional.
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Mono Light Cond}
This should be monospace condensed 000.
\end{document}

The only tricky part here is working out that the font is named using 'Cond' not 'Condensed': I checked the font files and opened the right one (lmmonoltcond10-regular.otf) in my system font manager to get that. You could alternatively have loaded the font by file name.

Thank you so much for your fast answer, accepted and upvoted. It works perfectly. I'll now study the fontspec package documentation.
